# Windows Azure Automation problems about job action 'Activate'

Tags: windows, azure

I am testing a runbook on Automation, but it was suspended. The details show : **The job action 'Activate' cannot be run, because the process stopped unexpectedly. The job action was attempted 3 times.**
I want to know how to solve this problem.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

This error message indicates that the process that runs the job crashed 3 times after attempted restarts. To help troubleshoot the issue test the script in the PowerShell ISE outside of Azure Automation.  If the script works there then the problem may be related to the Automation runbook worker (for example memory limit may have been reached).  In this case, you can post to the Azure Automation forum (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/home?forum=azureautomation), and include the JobId, Automation Account Name, date and time when the job was run.

Comment: Also if you post to the forum include the runbook name in addition to the above list info.